# YAML include automation

Tags: include, yaml

Using YAML to create and maintain config for my Python program, and love it. My config is huge, so it had to be divided into smaller logically distinct file and used the trick of `add_constructor()` with the tag `!include`.

The config is hierarchical, it looks like as follows (well, with a lot more levels). Sections have their own YAML files, in a directory structure corresponding to the config hierarchy (i.e. `A/B/C.yaml`):

```
A:
  B:
    C: !include A/B/C
```

The added constructor for the `!include` tag gets 2 arguments, the loader and the node objects, as usual. I am pretty sure that the path in the node graph can be somehow figured out from the loader and/or node object.

I tried to look up the node object, but it does not have path or any argument or method that would provide this info. Loader has references to parser and other methods in the load process, but I do not understand yet the YAML loading enough to figure out where the path is.

I am lazy and I only want to state a single "!include *this*" in my config, i.e. without specifying (again) the path in the hierarchy.

```
A:
  B:
    C: !include this
```

"this" is to be a sort-of keyword, so that the node value exists and I can leave the option open for specifying a real/different path. My constructor will then check the node value, and if the "this" keyword is found, calculates the path, otherwise uses the node value literally as the path.

Comment: What makes you "pretty sure" that he path in the node graph can be figured out? What library are you using? At least `ruamel.yaml` and `PyYAML` create this data structure depth first, and there is only an **empty** dict object available for the root level mapping (and the intermediates) when you reach `!include`. (the empty dict is necessary to allow for self recursion using anchors and aliases)

Comment: @Anthon Well the spec says *„Resolving the tag of a node must only depend on the following three parameters: […] (2) the path leading from the root to the node, […]“*, so I see how one would come to that conclusion. However, no YAML implementation I know (and certainly not the ones I authored) actually provides this information.

Comment: @flyx Thanks for that info. That it depends upon that path, doesn't necessarily mean that you actually use the path while you create the node, you can easily just select some different set of routines e.g. depending on being in flow or block parsing mode. The info is of course available if you traverse the call stack ...

Comment: @Anthon Yeah, I assume the reason for this statement is that an explicit tag somewhere up in the path may cause the value to be interpreted differently. For example, when serializing a declared class, you'd tag a mapping and then its keys will be interpreted as field names (as opposed to strings).

Comment: Glad to have your answers so prompt. Actually, let me edit the question an removed those "section" and "subsection" junk. The node graph path is the same as the file directory path.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do this instead:

```
!include_dir_hierarchy
  path: "."
  prefixes: [ Section_, Sub-section_, Sub-sub-section_ ]
```

Assuming `path` points to the root of the `A/B/C` hierarchy, you can then in the constructor walk the referenced path and generate the in-memory hierarchy based on the directory names and the list of prefixes. I deduce from your question that this kind of mapping between the file system path and the YAML hierarchy is possible.

Comment: After my edits/corrections in the question, no such ``prefixes`` is needed anymore. Could you please detail a bit the "you can then in the constructor walk the referenced path and generate the in-memory hierarchy", i.e. how actually I can do that?

Comment: @Netcreator Well basically, the constructor generates a dict. You navigate the file system using Python's stdlib, generating child dicts below the root one for each directory you discover. Most straightforward way to implement it would be recursion. If you have some detailed problem there, you'd best post it as new question.

Comment: My question is still the same, probably I need to rephrase it. I cannot navigate the file system until I know the graph path. I have no issues navigating the file path *after* I know the path. The graph path is to tell me where to navigate in the file system. If the constructor generates a dict (what's its name and location in the instances?), and it (or a chain of recursive constructors) is something that could tell the path from the root node to the actual node, please tell me how to get it. I will write a recursion as soon as I know what (dict or traceback or ?) to read in the recursion.

Comment: Okay, so the dict created by the constructor was a proposal about what *you* should do in the constructor code. It's not something that pre-exists. If you use my suggestion and register a constructor for that tag, you would first call the default constructor on the input which will give you a dict containing values for `'path'` and `'prefixes'`. You can then navigate the given path and generate the tree structure you actually want to return.

Comment: I still do not understand what to do. Let's drop this prefix thing, not needed. So I even if I have the following statement in the input stream, whatever "default" constructor I call, only get this node constructed and no any path: ``!include {'path'='.'}``. Probably the path should rather be built in the composer and new ``path`` attribute added to the Node slots. What I actually did was to construct a magic "!include" string in my added constructor, and a post-processor walks through the loaded data structure and recursively extends all such magic strings.

Comment: I guess I should have just shown some code. But if you have a solution that works now, that's not necessary anymore.